# Force iPhone to send an email with content type 'text/html'

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, gmail, content-type, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am successfully sending an email from my iPhone application using the available MFMailComposeViewController. The message's body is HTML, and it is showing up as such in all clients except Gmail. When I view the original message in Gmail, I notice that the message's Content Type is set to:

> Content-Type: multipart/alternative;

When sending the message, I am passing YES to the isHTML parameter:

```
[mailController setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:YES];`
```

Is there a way to force the mail to be sent with the 'text/html' Content Type? My understanding is that Gmail will default to displaying plain text if the message is not explicitly labeled otherwise.

EDIT:

Upon further inspection, it appears that Apple Mail is sending two versions of the message (one multipart/alternative and one text/html) to Gmail. It appears as though Google is defaulting to plain text when given the choice? If this is the case, I suppose the more appropriate question is as follows:

Can I force the email client on the iPhone to send ONLY the text/html version of the message?